# Elm: Update value in sub types

Tags: elm

I have this type

```
type alias Cat =
 { head : Head
 }

type alias Head =
  { eyes : Int
  , nose : Int
  , mouth : Mouth
  }

type alias Mouth =
  { tongue : Int
  , prey : Prey
  }

type alias Prey =
  { left : Int
  , right : Int 
  }
```

Inserting values

```
cat : Cat
cat = 
  { head = 
    { eyes = 2
    , nose = 1
    , mouth = 
      { tongue = 1
      , prey = 
        { left = 1
        , right = 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm usually doing this to change the right side of the prey

```
let  
  newCat = 
    (Cat 
      (Head oldValue.eyes oldValue.nose 
        (Mouth 
          (Prey oldValue.left 1)
        )
      )
    )
in
 ({model | cat = newCat }, Cmd.none)
```

And I hate hitting that, but I can not figure out how to do it the right way. When I try to do it right I can not return 'type cat'.

How to change the right prey in the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're already doing it the right way.

When you're dealing with nested records, you have to build them up, just like you're already doing.

Now, what you can do is abstract `newCat` and turn it into a function of type `Int -> Cat -> Cat`. Then, you'd be able to do `({model | cat = updateRightPrey 1 model.cat }, Cmd.none)`

But honestly, you may want to reconsider your data model. Does `Head`, `Mouth`, and `Prey` actually provide any value? What would you loose (and what would you have to gain) if you flatten your model like this:

```
type alias Cat = 
  { eyes : Eyes
  , nose : Nose
  , tongue : Tongue
  , left : Prey
  , right : Prey 
  }

type alias Eyes = Int
type alias Nose = Int
type alias Tongue = Int
type alias Prey = Int
```

Even if you change all those `Int` type alias to types...

```
type Eyes = Eyes Int
```

... it would be a lot simpler than dealing with nested records:

```
let
    cat = model.cat
in
({model | cat = { cat | right = 1 }, Cmd.none)
```

or...

```
let
    cat = model.cat
in
({model | cat = { cat | right = Prey 1 }, Cmd.none)
```